# How to reset BRAM to initial content using VHDL/Block design

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, bootloader, vivado, microblaze

I have just flashed a .bit file to the spi flash ram of my Nexys4 DDR (Artix7) board.

The bit file contains a Microblaze including bootloader in BRAM. The Microblaze is connected to a "local memory block" via DLMB/ILMB and via "axi smart connect" to an external DDR ram.

If I disconnect power and then connect power I see that the board restarts and that the bootloader correctly loads the firmware from DDR ram.

However if I use the reset button, then I see that the board resets but the bootloader in the Microblaze does not restart. The reset button is  connected to (among others) a "Processor System Reset" IP block that resets the microblaze.

I conclude that the local memory block/BRAM of the Microblaze is not reset to the initial values.

1. Where is the initial bootloader BRAM located? Is that the "local memory block" connected via DLMB/ILMB?
2. How can I reset BRAM to initial bootloader/bit file values?

Comment: BlockRAMs can not be reset in FPGAs. You need to reload / overwrite the BlockRAM again. If you need a full system reset, then trigger a reload of the SPI flash. If this is not possible, you need to use e.g. partial reconfiguration to selectively reprogram single BlockRAMs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now looking into the solution described here: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/Software-reset-of-MB-processor/td-p/188732